# Bug with ratings value in material-ui react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui

I have 3 different sets of ratings, that all need to be independent. The bug is when one of the ratings is clicked, only the first set(first to render) of ratings change. Meaning there seems to be a connection between all the different sets of ratings.

[image]

The main part concerning this bug is the method called AssetName.

```
function AssetName(props) {
  let localAssetName = [];
  let streamHolder = [];
  let holder = [];

  localAssetName.push("Asset 1");
  localAssetName.push("Asset 2");
  localAssetName.push("Asset 3");
  localAssetName.push("Asset 4");
  localAssetName.push("Asset 5");
  localAssetName.push("Asset 6");

  // this.setState({ assetNameAr : localAssetName});
  // this.setState({assetTest: true})
  props.parentCallback(localAssetName);
  let displasset = function displfcn() {
    for (let i1 = 0; i1 < localAssetName.length; i1++) {
      holder.push(
        <Grid container spacing={10}>
          <Grid item>
            <Box> {localAssetName[i1]}</Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item p={10} ml={10}>
            {/* Technical Expertise */}
            {/* <AssetLoop len ='1'/> */}
            <Rating max={3}> </Rating>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item p={10} ml={10}>
            {/* Business Knowledge */}
            {/* <AssetLoopBN len ='1'/> */}
            <Rating max={3}> </Rating>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item>
            {/* How recently have you worked on this asset? */}
            {/* <AssetLoopREC len = '1'/> */}
            <Rating max={4}> </Rating>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  };
  displasset(localAssetName);
  return holder;
}
```

Comment: I have added the name = , value for each rating tag. Which helped decouple them from each other. But I do not know why only the first row of each set of ratings is being changed on click and not the actual set of ratings I clicked.

Comment: Hi @Team22. Can you provide a codesanbox for this?

Comment: I think you have forgot to pass a `key` on render

Answer (score 7):

The "name" property of Rating must be unique.
[Similar issue on material ui's github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18387)

Comment: Glad I found your answer only 1 hour into this mess  @notAnkur !